# Python: Test whether CSV matches SQL types

Tags: python, sql

I have a problem, where I have an CSV file and corresponding SQL types. The script should now check, whether the individual columns correspond to these types or not - e.g.:

```
A       B       C          D
'Test'  '1'     '1.23454'  '2018-05-05'
'Test2' 'a'     '12.1'     '2018-05-05-12:45:15'
```

And together with the following sql types:

```
A: varchar(15)
B: int
C: double(12,1)
D: timestamp
```

So when running this script, for the first line, the casts of column A and B are successful, but C not (too many positions after the comma) and neither does D (date instead of timestamp)

The second line fails, because column B contains a text and not a number.

Is there a simple way to test, that these casts are possible without having to actually load them into the database?

Kind regards.

Comment: If you write the format specifications into a file and check the format of the CSV file with the *chkcsv* Python program:http://chkcsv.readthedocs.io/.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to open the file, iterate through it, and check that each of the fields are of the type you expect.

So for the first column, you would validate length:

```
if len(column_a_string) >= 15: 
    raise TypeError("Invalid string length for column_a_string.")
```

Column B you would validate that it is an int:

```
if not column_b_int.isdigit():
    raise TypeError("Unable to parse column_b_int to integer value.")
```

Column C, check that you're able to cast the value to a float:

```
try:
    float(column_c_float)
except ValueError:
    print "Unable to cast column_c_float to a floating-point value."
```

And for the final column:

```
import datetime
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(column_d_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Unable to parse column_d_date to a date")
```